# DataTables not working in Laravel blade template

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, datatables

Blade template in question:

```
@extends('2a.layouts.master')
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"> 
</script>


@section('content')
    <div class="row">
        <table class="table" id="tablegg">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="text-center">#</th>
                <th class="text-center">First Name</th>
                <th class="text-center">Last Name</th>
                <th class="text-center">Email</th>
                <th class="text-center">Gender</th>
                <th class="text-center">Country</th>
                <th class="text-center">Salary ($)</th>
                <th class="text-center">Actions</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>fgfgfd</td>
                <td>gfdgf</td>
                <td>gfdgdf</td>
                <td>gfdgg</td>
                <td>aaaaa</td>
                <td>bbbbbb</td>
                <td>ccccc</td>
                <td>dddddd</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>fgfgfd</td>
                <td>dddddd</td>
                <td>ccccccc</td>
                <td>bbbbbbb</td>
                <td>aaaaa</td>
                <td>bbbbbb</td>
                <td>ccccc</td>
                <td>dddddd</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

@endsection
@section('scripts')

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#tablegg').DataTable();
    });
</script>

@endsection
```

master template (included in every file)

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/upload/core.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/upload/upload.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/upload/bootstrap.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/notification.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/ajaxSearch/ajaxSearch.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/ajaxSearch/something.js') }}"></script>

@yield('scripts')
```

Unfortunately, even though I am getting the DataTable() suggesting in my code it is still not working. Inside of console I receive this error: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function.

Method 1:
I am loading jquery first and then loading jquery.datatables at the top of the template. I looked up the error and it says it is being caused by not loading jquery first. I can place them at the top of the template (doesn't work) or place them in order inside of master template (doesn't work)

Method 2: 
I used npm install datatables. This method unfortunately still did not work. Though I did not recieve the same error in the console which was worse because then I had no idea what was wrong. I made sure not to have any typos, and am trying to create only the most basic functionality.

I have the script that calls DataTable() inside of a @yield('scripts') tag. Meaning that it should not run that script until all others have been loaded.

I am using Laravel 5.5 on WAMP server. I have restarted the server as well to see if it helped.

I am not sure what else to try. I could not find anything here on stack overflow or elsewhere to suggest other fixes. I thought I was getting close when I got the error to go away after using npm install but it did not.

Edit: I also used npm install datatables.net, I made sure to only use one at a time because I read having multiple similar files of the code would cause issues.

Comment: I think the `JQuery` and `DataTable` plugins must be included inside `@section('content')`

Comment: Reorder to jquery on first place then jquery.datatables on second place

Comment: Just a thought: Does bootstrap not also need jQuery? Maybe you should it put in your master template... See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried putting them in your section `scripts` like this:

```
@section('scripts')
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#tablegg').DataTable();
    });
</script>

@endsection
```

and your CSS put it in your master template in the `<head>` tag.

Also to mention here, I see you use `bootstrap` in your main layout file, so for that you use jQuery, you might not even need to put it here, just the `datatable` script should be sufficient.

Comment: @RyanF please look at the edit of my answer in case you experience conflicts with the jQuery library.

Comment: That worked. Why did that work, can you explain further in your answer? I don't understand why section('scripts') was being executed before what was at the top of the template.

Comment: I had tried without including jquery as well before. I forgot to mention that in my post.

Comment: You must put the scripts in the section that you are yielding, otherwise they are not being used at all as you had them. So everything that is surrounded with a `@section` tag will exist in the view once you render it.

Please consider accepting the answer if it solved your issue. Thanks

Comment: `@yield('scripts')` is replaced with your `@section('scripts')` so if you look at your template your scripts are out of any section so that means they are not rendered in the view at all. Hope this clarifies it a bit better.